# Extracting multiple data items from LinkedList() element

Tags: android, sqlite, linked-list

I have a problem with an Android SQLite Database Example with the following code in MainActivity that fails to build;

"error: cannot find symbol method getTitle()"

```
    // get all books
    list = db.getAllBooks();
    List listTitle = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        listTitle.add(i, list.get(i).getTitle());
                }
```

The getAllBooks() query works fine, however the code is meant to extract the title of a book from the LinkedList() named list that was populated by the query. If I drop off the getTitle() like this...

```
    // get all books
    list = db.getAllBooks();
    List listTitle = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        listTitle.add(i, list.get(i));
                }
```

I get data returned as expected in the new ArrayList() named listTitle

```
Book [id=1, title=The Great Gatsby, author=F. Scott Fitzgerald]
Book [id=2, title=Load of rubbish, author=A. Nonymouse]
Book [id=3, title=A lot more rubbish, author=A.Nonymouse]
Book [id=4, title=Anna Karenina, author=Leo Tolstoy]
Book [id=5, title=The Grapes of Wrath, author=John Steinbeck]
Book [id=6, title=Invisible Man, author=Ralph Ellison]
Book [id=7, title=Gone with the Wind, author=Margaret Mitchell]
Book [id=8, title=Pride and Prejudice, author=Jane Austen]
Book [id=9, title=Sense and Sensibility, author=Jane Austen]
Book [id=10, title=Mansfield Park, author=Jane Austen]
Book [id=11, title=The Color Purple, author=Alice Walker]
Book [id=12, title=The Temple of My Familiar, author=Alice Walker]
Book [id=13, title=The waves, author=Virginia Woolf]
Book [id=14, title=Mrs Dalloway, author=Virginia Woolf]
Book [id=15, title=War and Peace, author=Leo Tolstoy]
```

Of course, I was just wanting the title in the new list to display on the device, so the issue is how do I access the individual id or title or author from the LinkList() returned by the query..?

Comment: What is it what `db.getAllBooks()` returns? Guess some kind of collection, does single object from that collection have `getTitle()` method?

Comment: It's a string array the Book [id=1 etc...] above. I can now access method getTitle() due to answer by quocnhat7 Thanks for your interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please indicate correct object type for your List/ArrayList like this:

```
// get all books
List<Book> list = db.getAllBooks();
List<String> listTitle = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    listTitle.add(i, list.get(i).getTitle());
}
```

Of course, class Book has getTitle() method.

When you do not indicate correct object type of List, it will read as a list of Object, not a list of Book in your case.

Comment: Great, that works perfectly..! I think I'll need to raise another question to get getId() working

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping that inside that list everything is String

```
int firstPOs=listTitle.get(i).indexOf(',');
int secondPos=listTitle.get(i).lastIndexOf('',);

String id=listTitle.get(i).substring(3,firstPos);
String title=listTitle.get(i).substring(firstPos+7,secondPos);
String authorlistTitle.get(i).substring(secondPos+8,listTile.get(i).length());
```

Comment: You are right, the contents are a string, however there is a method to extract this info as expleined by quocnhat7 Thanks for your interest.